# What is acctinputoctets?

Tags: radius, freeradius

I have been looking for a definite meaning of acctinputoctets or acctoutputoctets
and i have been using it as bytes.

but what is the real unit of this attribute?. I don't understand octets and it is too ambiguous.

Can you explain in Lay mans term, Thank you for those who can help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally after testing the data usage using

[NETWORKZ](https://www.softperfect.com/products/networx/) and [GLASS WIRE](https://www.glasswire.com/)

And monitoring traffic on an [ASUS ROUTER](https://www.asus.com/PH/Networking/RTAC87U/)

I conclude that this is in **bytes!**

How the test conducted:

- Using an account connected to the radius limited to 5MB and 50MB all
  traffic/data usage was somewhere between 98-100%.

Meaning if the limit was 5MB

1. results on radius is 5.2~5.5
2. results on Networkz is 5.1~5.7
3. results on Glasswire is 4.9-5.2
4. results on Router is 5.2~5.6

Hope this could help someone

Comment: Your answer could be better if it actually answered your own question. :)  What is `acctinputoctets`? Download or upload?

Comment: sorry i did not read about your comment @Houman, btw acctinputoctets = download, acctoutputoctets = upload

Comment: No problem. Thanks buddy.